# Why is favicon.ico being passed as a parameter even though it doesn't even exist in the project?

Tags: typescript, next.js13

I'm building a web app using Next.js 13's app router. I have a dynamic page  which fetches some data and displays it. For some reason, even though favicon.ico does not exist in my project, I get errors in the console from within the fetch logic about an invalid id number "favicon.ico". Here is the code & error:

Code:

```js
// /app/[id]/page.tsx

import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { authOptions } from "../api/auth/[...nextauth]/route";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import fetchSearchParams from "#/lib/fetchSearchParams";
import fetchViewpointEmployeeData from "#/lib/fetchViewpointEmployeeData";
import fetchEmployeeSafetyProfile, {
  transformToAwardData,
} from "#/lib/fetchEmployeeSafetyProfile";
import { EmployeeInfo } from "#/ui/employee-info";
import { EmptyInfo } from "#/ui/empty-info";

type ProfilePageProps = {
  params: { id: number };
};

export default async function Page({ params }: ProfilePageProps) {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

  if (!session) {
    redirect("/login");
  }

  const searchParams = await fetchSearchParams();
  const viewpointEmployeeData = await fetchViewpointEmployeeData(params.id);
  const employeeSafetyProfile = await fetchEmployeeSafetyProfile(params.id);

  const awardData = employeeSafetyProfile
    ? transformToAwardData(employeeSafetyProfile)
    : null;

  return (
    <div>
      {!viewpointEmployeeData || !employeeSafetyProfile ? (
        <EmptyInfo searchParams={searchParams} />
      ) : (
        <EmployeeInfo
          searchParams={searchParams}
          viewpointData={viewpointEmployeeData}
          safetyProfile={employeeSafetyProfile}
          awardData={awardData}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Error:

```bash
Error: No employee found for given id: favicon.ico
    at fetchViewpointEmployeeData (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./lib/fetchViewpointEmployeeData.ts:71:19)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Page (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/[id]/page.tsx:41:35)
Error: No profile found for given id: favicon.ico
    at fetchEmployeeSafetyProfile (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./lib/fetchEmployeeSafetyProfile.ts:17:19)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Page (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/[id]/page.tsx:42:35
```

I can't find anything online about this, and am seeing if someone else has encountered this problem. I'm finding this quite troubling as id is of type number so how can "favicon.ico" be passed as a parameter?

Comment: The browser is trying to fetch `/favicon.ico` from the root, but it's getting caught by this page.

Comment: why? I don't even have favicon.ico in the project, is it required?

Comment: No, browsers just do that automatically. They try to fetch the favicon.

Comment: Edit your _app.tsx or _document.tsx or whatever I'm out of touch with the new Next.js versions to include a "fake" favicon to discourage the browser from trying to fetch one.